# SiteMinder Single-Sign-On without installing agent on web application server

Tags: single-sign-on, siteminder

Our IT staff refuses to install the SiteMinder agent on our application's IIS 6.0 web server, citing security concerns as it is a third-party software, as well as the possibility of high resource utilization impacting application performance.

They suggest that we set up an independent, segregated web server containing only a bare-bones IIS, the SiteMinder Agent, and a "shim" to authenticate login attempts.

This shim would be a single ASPX page marked to be protected by the agent. It would use the SiteMinder agent to authenticate the user ID, look up the user ID in the application's database, and return the user ID and password to the user's browser. A JavaScript function would then POST the user ID and password to the application's existing login page as if they typed it in themselves.

Are their concerns warranted?  Why or why not?

Have you ever heard of anyone implementing a similar architecture?

Is their proposed solution good, bad, or ugly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not look like it would work, because the agent manages not only the initial login, but subsequent calls to the application, i.e. authenticated session.  The agent examines the cookie, validates it, etc. Your scenario does not describe how that would happen.

In our environment, all internet traffic goes through an Apache reverse proxy before hitting IIS.  IIS is behind firewall. The Apache reverse proxy has the SM agent all it  does is redirect the traffic to IIS.  I suppose it would be feasible to do a similar setup with IIS acting as a reverse proxy.

BTW, tell your IT guy that his proposed shoestring and bubblegum login solution is a much bigger security concern than installing SiteMinder on IIS.

Comment: I know, right? Thanks for the reply; this is exactly the non-biased third-party opinion I needed, though I wish you had also mentioned the security issues around the idea sending the application's id/password back to the client. (!!!) In their scenario, the session is handled by the application's built-in id/password authentication and SSO only knows about a single protected resource: the "shim" that sends the user their application password.

"shoestring and bubblegum", lol. Classic.

Answer (score 2):

The apache reverse proxy solution will definitely work, but with SiteMinder r12.51, Secure Proxy Server is included, which is basically SiteMinder's version of a reverse proxy (plus a lot more).

SPS will let you configure a single server as a "gateway" for all of your applications that can't or won't install a SiteMinder agent.  The web agent is embedded in SPS and a proprietary Java app does the heavy lifting.  SPS also has a GUI which follows the look and feel of the r12 WAMUI, which makes configuring it very simple.

Secure Proxy Server also has a Federation Gateway feature, so you don't need to install the web agent option pack if you are doing SAML Federation.  All of your fcc pages can also be served by the SPS, so you can reduce the number of webservers needed to support your SSO environment.